# Showing proof using contrapositive

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Tell if the statement is true or false. If true provide a proof.

$\forall x$ $\in R$  $\left(\forall M > 1 \left(x \ge 1-\frac{1}{M}\right) \to x \ge 1 \right)$

I believe this statement is True.

The contrapositive is

$\forall x$ $\in R$  $\left(x<1 \to \exists M >1 \left(x< 1 - \frac{1}{m} \right) \right)$

**Proof:**

Suppose $x < 1$ and let $M_0 > 1$. then $1-\frac{1}{M_0} < 1$. Therefore $x<1$ if $x <1-\frac{1}{M_0}$

**commentary**

Since this is an if,then statement I assumed the let hand side. Since there is an introduction of an element M, and $\exists$ symbol is given, I introduced it as an arbitrary element. Then, it's clear that $1-\frac{1}{M_0} < 1$. I feel like this is incomplete at best. Although logically I can see why it works, I don't think I've really proved it.

Comment: You have shown that both $x$ and $1-\frac{1}{M_0}$ are less than one yet you have not shown $x < 1-\frac{1}{M_0}$.

Comment: @miracle173 Please note that your changing $\;\to\;$ to $\;\implies\;$ may not be an improvement for the OP, but instead confusing: different people and institutions and schools use different notations. I usually try to adopt the OP's notation where possible, to not distract from the essence of the question...  I think the consensus on math.se is that changing notation in a question is Not Done (tm).

Comment: @MarnixKlooster I rolled the edit back. I missed that this is already an old question. It was on the "top questions" list.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

The "issue" is with $x$ *positive* : for $x \le 0$, it is enough to choose $M=2$ and we have :

> $x \le 0 < 1- \frac 1 2=\frac 1 2$.

For $x$ positve, consider $\delta=1-x > 0$ (because $x < 1$).

Thus :

> $x=1 - \delta$.

Choose $M$ such that $M \ge \frac 1 \delta$ and :

$x \le 1 - \frac 1 M$.

__

You have to prove an "if___, then___" statement : correct.

So you have to *assume* the let hand side, but then you have to *show* that the right one holds, i.e. you have to prove that "there is" an element $M$ : you cannot simply assume it.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you want to prove "$\exists M>1,\dots$", so you have to **give** such a $M$. It won't work with **any** $M > 1$.

Let $x<1$. Two cases :

- Either $x<0$, then $M=2$ is ok.
- Either $0 \leqslant x < 1$. We pose $M = \frac2{1-x}$. Then 
  $$ 1 - \frac1M = 1 - \frac{1-x}2 = \frac{1+x}2$$
  And obviously, $x < \frac{1+x}2$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more 'calculational' approach to this proof: let's see if we can simplify the antecedent $\;\forall M > 1 \left ( x \ge 1 - \frac 1 M \right )\;$ and in that way reach the conclusion $\;x \ge 1\;$.  The most complex expression to deal with is $\;x \ge 1 - \frac 1 M\;$, and it seems helpful if we can isolate $\;M\;$ on one side.$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\then}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\when}{\leftarrow}
\newcommand{\equiv}{\leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
$

---

We calculate as follows, for any $\;x \in R\;$ and any $\;M > 1\;$:
$$\calc
    x \ge 1 - \frac 1 M
\op\equiv\hint{arithmetic -- separate $1$ and $\;\frac 1 M\;$, to isolate $\;M\;$}
    \frac 1 M \ge 1 - x
\op\equiv\hints{take reciprocal on both sides, using $\ref 1$ below}\hint{with $\;y,z := M,1-x\;$, and using $\;M > 0\;$}
    1-x \le 0 \;\lor\; M \le \frac 1 {1-x}
\endcalc$$

Now we can use the above to simplify the consequent:
$$\calc
    \forall M > 1 \left ( x \ge 1 - \frac 1 M \right )
\op\equiv\hint{by the above calculation}
    \forall M > 1 \left ( 1-x \le 0 \;\lor\; M \le \frac 1 {1-x} \right )
\op\equiv\hint{logic: extract part not containing $\;M\;$ out of $\;\forall M\;$}
    1-x \le 0 \;\lor\; \forall M > 1 \left ( M \le \frac 1 {1-x} \right )
\op\equiv\hint{simplify LHS; RHS is false, witness $\;M := \frac 1 {1-x} + 1\;$}
    x \ge 1
\endcalc$$

---

Here we used the following law of arithmetic to take the reciprocal on both sides of an inequality:
$$
\tag{0}
\frac 1 y \ge z \;\equiv\;
\left (y > 0 \land z \le 0 \right )
\;\lor\;
\left (y > 0 \land y \le \frac 1 z \right )
\;\lor\;
\left (z < 0 \land y \le -\frac 1 z \right )
$$
which simplifies to
$$
\tag{1}
\frac 1 y \ge z \;\equiv\; z \le 0 \;\lor\; y \le \frac 1 z
$$
for $\;y > 0\;$.

Note how the 'case split' in this proof is contained in the $\;\lor\;$ in $\ref 1$.

Finally, note how the above proof proves a stronger result than was required: it proves $\;\equiv\;$ instead of $\;\then\;$.  And it can be made even stronger by throughout replacing the $\;1\;$ in $\;M \gt 1\;$ by any larger number: nothing else in the proof would have to be changed.